# Radio buttons not marked in red when validation failed (works only with IE)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I set client side validation on my ajax form (loaded with jQuery dialog). When submitting my form, under Internet Explorer, I can clearly see which fields are not correct (see below: 2 textbox + radio buttons).

[image]

When I test under another browser like Firefox, the radio buttons are not marked in red like IE do (see below).

[image]

Does someone have an idea why or what I have to do to see show these red marks?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

When I grap the source of my page at runtime, here is what I have for my first radio button:

```
<input name="ADR" class="input-validation-error" id="ADRYes" type="radio" data-val-required="Le champ ADR est requis" data-val="true" value="Yes"/>
```

So I have valid tags for validation.

Now when I debug under IE (developper tools) here is what I can see:
[image]

And when I debug under Firefox here is what I can see:
[image]

I can see valid html tags for validation BUT no styles are set on radio buttons because Firefox, Chrome, Safari don't allow radio buttons to have borders or background-color.

Comment: Can't say much without seeing code...

Comment: I updated my question to include more infos and code. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `outline` instead of `border`:

```
.input-validation-error {
    background-color: #ffeeee;
    outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to narrow outline just to the radio boxes?

Comment: nvm, I figured it out.. input[type="radio"].input-validation-error {
 outline : 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Darin - I use jquery.validation.js and just added

```
outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
```

to my CSS

```
input.error{border:1px solid red;outline: 1px solid red;}
textarea.error{border: 1px solid red;}
```